# Why is TeamCity ignoring my web project's package/publish settings when executing my build via MSBuild?

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, msdeploy, vs-web-application-project, teamcity-7.0

When I run the following msbuild command:

```
msbuild /t:Package /p:Configuration=Release;PackageLocation={MY PACKAGE LOCATION}
```

My package is created correctly and the contents of my SetParameters file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<parameters>
  <setParameter name="IIS Web Application Name" value="Default Web Site/SiteNameIWant" />
</parameters>
```

"SiteNameIWant" comes directly from my web application project file:

```
<DeployIisAppPath>Default Web Site/SiteNameIWant</DeployIisAppPath>
```

I have my web application project file configured this way for both the Debug and Release configurations.

When I run my build via TeamCity, however, my site name comes out as "SiteNameIWant.csproj_deploy".  I have found a workaround by explicitly adding a build parameter:

```
system.DeployIisAppPath=Default Web Site/SiteNameIWant
```

However, I'm not satisfied with this solution because TeamCity is ignoring the value (set per configuration) in my web application project.

**How do I get TeamCity to respect my web application project file's setting?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always something obvious, isn't it?  Not surprisingly, **the problem was with me**, not TeamCity.  :D

I realized what was happening was that the change that I had applied to my web application project file for the `DeployIisAppPath` setting was not committed to source control.  So, running `msbuild` locally worked but TeamCity was still getting the old value that had not yet been updated in source control.  Doh!